# How to access custom UDFs through Spark Thrift Server?

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr, spark-thriftserver

I am running Spark Thrift Server on EMR.  I start up the Spark Thrift Server by:

```
  sudo -u spark /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --queue interactive.thrift --jars /opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar
```

Notice that I have a customer UDF jar and I want to add it to the Thrift Server classpath, so I added --jars /opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar in the above command.

Once I am in my EMR, I issued the following to connect to the Spark Thrift Server.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

Then I was able to issue command like show databases.  But how do I access the custom UDF?  I thought by adding the *--jars* option in the Thrift Server startup script, that would add the jar for Hive resource to use as well.

The only way I can access the custom UDF now is by adding the customer UDF jar to Hive resource

```
add jar /opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar
```

Then create function of the UDF.

**Question:**
Is there a way to auto config the custom UDF jar without adding jar each time to the spark session?

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this? For clarity, the `custom-udfs.jar`, does it contain Spark SQL udfs or Hive UDFs (implemented as extensions of the hive UDF class)?

Comment: @Kentt Do you know the answer for either case? Spark SQL UDF or Hive UDF?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit the file `start-thriftserver.sh`, at the end:

1. Wait server is ready
2. Execute setup SQL query

You could also post a proposal on JIRA, this is a very good feature "Execute setup code at start up".

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that the `--jars` should be positioned correctly; which should be the first argument. I too had trouble getting the jars to work properly. This worked for me

```
# if your spark installation is in /usr/lib/
sudo -u spark /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh  \
  --jars /path/to/jars/jar1.jar,/path/to/jars/jar2.jar \
  --properties-file ./spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf \ # this is only needed if you want to customize spark configuration, it looks similar to spark-defaults.conf
  --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2
```