# How to register custom UDF jar in HiveThriftServer2?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr, spark-thriftserver

In HiveThriftServer2 class, what is the difference between calling the [startWithContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala#L55) vs calling the [main](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala#L73)?

I have a customer UDF jar that I want to register, so that every time when the thrift server boots up, all these are auto configure.  Is there a way to do this?

Can I use Hive context to register the UDF jar and functions and call the HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext to start up the server?

Thanks

Comment: If you add the JAR onto the CLASSPATH, then restart the server, it'll get auto configured

Comment: And calling `main` kills all previous SparkContext

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you clarify what you mean by adding the JAR onto the CLASSPATH?  I tried to start the Thrift Server by **sudo -u $SVC_USER /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh  --jars /opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar** but this doesn't register the custom-udfs.jar.  Thanks

Comment: Well, I was thinking `$SPARK_HOME/jars`, or you give `--jars` with the spark executor, not the server, as mentioned here. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_spark-component-guide/content/calling-udfs.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access custom UDFs through Spark Thrift Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553037/how-to-access-custom-udfs-through-spark-thrift-server)

Comment: And please don't repost your quesitons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `hive.aux.jars.path`, and it's a Hive property, not Spark specific.

I personally haven't tried it, but I'm thinking something like this

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
  --hiveconf hive.aux.jars.path=file:///opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar
```

References

- [Running Spark ThriftServer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server)
- [Managing HiveServer2 UDFs](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_mc_hive_udf.html#concept_un3_yrm_2r)

Comment: I tried your suggestion doing `./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
  --hiveconf hive.aux.jars.path=file:///opt/lib/custom-udfs.jar` Then connect to Thrift Server via Beeline `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default` . But when I `list jars`, the custom-udfs.jar is still not listed as a resource.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried copying the jar into spark folder or not?

Comment: I got this working by having the custom-udfs.jar in the `/usr/lib/hive/auxlib` directory instead of `/opt/lib/`.  Like you suggested, specify `hive.aux.jars.path` pointing to it.  This is working because I don't need to do `add jar` once I am connected via Beeline before creating a function.  My question is now how come the hive `list jars` command doesn't list the custom-udfs.jar?

Comment: Not sure. Probably a bug